# Eclipse JavaEditor extension: How to add a properly indented line?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.4

### What is needed?

We are writing [an extension](http://vrapper.sf.net) to eclipse's JavaEditor. We need a way to add a line before and after the line the cursor is in.

The cursor on the new line should be on the correct position (correctly indeted).

### Sample (# is the cursor):

before (`I`):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main#(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }
}
```

after wanted (`II`):

```
public class Test {
    #
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }
```

after not wanted (a.k.a. the present state) (`III`):

```
public class Test {
#
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }
```

### Present state:

The transformation from `I` to `III` can be done via `IDocument.replace()`, an `InsertEdit` or via `IDocumentExtension4`'s rewriteSessions.

The problem is how to call JavaEditor's indent function after inserting the new line from the extension. Or is it even possible to indent the line directly correct (`I` to `II`)? (The length of the indent should **not** always be the one of the current line, but the correct one. `internal` packages should not be used if possible, otherwise `IndentUtil` would be the solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution seems to be not to use `IDocument.replace()`, e.g.

```
myTextViewer.getDocument().replace(...)
```

but `insert()`, e.g.

```
textViewer.getTextWidget().insert(...)
```

That works but is not yet a complete solution to call the indent function without generating dependencies to `org.eclipse.jdt` :-(. That is still needed.